# How to append a string to a list item in Python?

Tags: python, string

Assume that I have a list:

```
l = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

How to append `pre` to `bar` to have:

```
l = ['foo', 'prebar', 'baz']
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use + operand to concatenate strings together.So you can use a list comprehension to loop over your list and change the item that is equal with `'bar'` :

```
>>> l1=['pre'+i if i=='bar' else i for i in l1]
>>> l1
['foo', 'prebar', 'baz']
```

Comment: Thanks Kasra. BTW, love your motto! :)

Answer (score 2):

Lists are mutable; strings are not. Therefore, assuming you know the index of the string you want to change:

```
l = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
i = 1
l[i] = 'pre' + l[i]
```

This gives `l = ['foo', 'prebar', 'baz']`.

Using a list comprehension constructs a whole new list in memory, which is wasteful of resources (though immaterial for small lists). This method modifies the existing list in place.

Comment: Using a slice assignment with a generator expression eliminates the objection of creating a new list, but I agree that directly modifying the desired item is the best approach when possible. If you don't know what item you want to change, that's what `list.index()` is for!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the other answer you can also alter the list directly:

```
l[1] = l[1] + "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=['pre'+i if i=='bar' else i for i in l]
l
['foo', 'prebar', 'baz']
```

**result**

```
['foo', 'prebar', 'baz']
```